# How to import .csv file to my datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, csv-import

My used code is:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim fName As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\desktop"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    txtpathfile.Text = fName
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String

    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

My output looks wrongly encoded:
[image]

What's wrong with my code? Please help me. Thank you for consideration.

Comment: The selected file's contents looks like a zip archive

Comment: No sir, it's not a zip file. Why my output is something like a barcode?

Comment: That output would indicate that you're reading the file using the wrong encoding to read the file, thus the bytes that are read are converted to the wrong characters.  You will need to specify an encoding when creating the `StreamReader`, e.g. `Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName, Text.Encoding.ASCII)`.  If you don't know what encoding was used to write the file then you'll have to try a few different ones to see which works.

Comment: By the way, you are not closing the file when you are finished with it.  I would recommend a `Using` statement to create the `StreamReader` to ensure that the file is closed, which happens implicitly at the `End Using` statement.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Sir, actually my code is from online search only, so I am not familiar with these, but I'm trying to study it. Could you please explain to me the "Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName, Text.Encoding.ASCII)", what is the use of "Text.Encoding.ASCII"? Thanks

Comment: I already told you what it's for.  If you don't understand my explanation or you need more information then do the appropriate research.  We're not here to teach you the basics of VB.NET programming. We're here to help with specific coding issues and I have done that.  You are quite capable of using the Help menu in VS to open the documentation for that `StreamReader` constructor and reading about it for yourself.

Comment: I tried to add tags for more visibility for your question.

Comment: I have a lot of trials for this code but I really don't get it. I do also some research but I can't find any answer to my question. Can you suggest me, what is the best table I should use for importing excel in vb.net? for example: datagridview, listviewitem or reportviewer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I arrived here from google. Just in case someone sarching for a quick code to copy:

```
    Private Sub ReadCSV()
        Dim fName As String = "C:\myfile.csv"
        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim SplitLine() As String

        If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
            Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName, Encoding.ASCII)
                Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                    SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ";")
                    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
                Loop
            End Using
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that has been looking for other solution, this works and let me add, delete and update the same datagrid without any problem

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                file_path.Text = ofd.FileName
                Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).ToList()
                Dim list As List(Of User) = New List(Of User)
                fill_Columns(lines)
                For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Count - 1
                    Dim data As String() = lines(i).Split(",")
                    addElements(
                    data(0),
                    data(1),
                    data(2),
                    data(3),
                    data(4)
                ) 'All this elements has to match with the -fill_Columns- elements
                Next
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Use it on the button where you want to click it... Also add this

```
    Private Sub fill_Columns(lines As List(Of String))
        Dim columns() As String = lines(0).Split(",")
        For Each item In columns
            Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            col.HeaderText = item
            col.Name = item
            col.DataPropertyName = item
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub addElements(Code As String, Name As String, Birth As DateTime, Email As String, Address As String)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                Code,
                Name,
                Birth.ToString,
                Email,
                Address
            ) 'You add or delete as you need
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

This is really work!

```
Dim fName As String = ""
   OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\desktop"
       OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"  
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    txtpathfile.Text = fName
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String


    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(txtpathfile.Text, Encoding.ASCII)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ";")
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
```

Comment: You should include the 'Encoding.ASCII' in your streamreader.